# Error : [type] is not a function when using angular-chart

Tags: angularjs, charts

Error from console :

```
angular.min.js:114TypeError: (intermediate value)[type] is not a function
at createChart (ADapp.js:559)
at Object.fn (ADapp.js:512)
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:138)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:141)
at angular.min.js:21
at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
at Ac.c (angular.min.js:20)
at Ac (angular.min.js:21)
at de (angular.min.js:20)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:306)
```

this is the index.html

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/_jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
   <script src="~/AngularApp/js/ADapp.js"></script>
   <script src="~/AngularApp/js/ADapp.html.templates.js"></script>
```

trying to enable this Chart :

```
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"></canvas>
```

what i am messing ?

Update :

fixed by changing the html from char-data to data

Comment: posting an [mcve] will help...

Comment: Could it be the space between chart- and labels? Should it perhaps be 'chart-labels' ?

Comment: thanks but its not the problem my mistake